# Apache Lucene : Static Instances of Index Reader and Writer across Application

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Apache Lucene 6.3.0 to add a 'search and report' functionality in a web app. I read the following **note** in the javadoc of 'IndexWriter' ([Link](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html))

> NOTE: IndexWriter instances are completely thread safe, meaning multiple threads can call any of its methods, concurrently. If your application requires external synchronization, you should not synchronize on the IndexWriter instance as this may cause deadlock; use your own (non-Lucene) objects instead.

Similar note is available for IndexReader

This prompted me to create a Global and static instance IndexReader available throughout the application.

I am unable to measure performance improvement of static instance vs local instance.

What would be considered a better approach? Static or local?

**EDIT :**

I have reached the last stage of my project using Apache Lucene. I have made a list of [Observations and Suggestions](https://github.com/chanchalkariwala/Lucene/blob/master/README.md), based on my experience.
It is a link to a GitHub Project's README, since that is a document that I'm more likely to update regularly.

Comment: it's really broad question, depends a lot on use cases, i think

Comment: I ended up reading an older version of 'Lucene in Action'. It states that one instance of both Reader and Writer can be used for all operations, since : 1. It is thread safe and 2. Opening a new instance can be a costly process. Still haven't been able to measure performance difference.